# How do i properly use CustomVars in google analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

How do i properly use custom vars in google analytics? I used the code below and here is what i notice

1. i only seen 'one' being in the get request
2. After 24 hours only 'one' showed up
3. After commenting out one and changing the 2 vars to use slotIndex-1 i notice NO vars going through GA

What am i doing wrong?

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-12345678-1']);

if (cond) {
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1, 'one', d1,1]); 
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2, 'name two', "sz",1]); 
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',3, 'name3', boolVal,1]); 
}
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function () {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Comment: Things look fine, assuming `cond` evaluates to true somehow.

Comment: @eduardocereto i am not 100% sure since it was a year ago but i believe just waiting 24hours (for google analytic to update) solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code looks fine, although you might want to make sure your variables exist and convert to strings.

```
if (cond) {
    if (typeof d1 !== "undefined") {
        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'one', d1.toString(), 1]);
    }
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'name two', "sz", 1]);
    if (typeof boolVal !== "undefined") {
        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'name3', boolVal.toString(), 1]);
    }
}
```

Also, Custom Variables can lag behind _trackPageview's showing up in the GA UI. (Source: [Mastering Google Analytics Custom Variables](http://cutroni.com/blog/2011/05/18/mastering-google-analytics-custom-variables/))